# Navigate to a cell in a DataFrame using a set of criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv table like so:

```
a, b, c, d
value, value, value, value
value, value, value, value
```

which I'm loading into a `DataFrame`. I also have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = {'a': some_value, 'b' = some_value, 'c' = some_value}
```

I want to navigate to the cell in column `d` where the row has values `a`, `b` and `c` as specified by this dictionary. I know that there exists exactly one cell that matches these criteria. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the data into a dataframe, then use a merge:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,2,3,4],'d':[1,2,3,4]})

lookup = {'a':2,'b':2, 'c':2}

lookupdf = pd.DataFrame(lookup, index = [1]) #need the index, as they are all scalar

pd.merge(lookupdf, data)


    a   b   c   d
0   2   2   2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, would be use `reduce` on boolean conditions

```
In [1034]: data[np.logical_and.reduce(pd.DataFrame(data[x] == lookup[x] for x in lookup))]
Out[1034]:
   a  b  c  d
1  2  2  2  2

In [1035]: data[reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [data[x] == lookup[x] for x in lookup])]
Out[1035]:
   a  b  c  d
1  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, could be using `pd.query`

```
In [1009]: query = ' and '.join(['%s == %s' % (x, lookup[x]) for x in lookup])

In [1010]: query
Out[1010]: 'a == 2 and c == 2 and b == 2'

In [1011]: data.query(query)
Out[1011]:
   a  b  c  d
1  2  2  2  2
```

Details

```
In [1012]: lookup
Out[1012]: {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}

In [1013]: data
Out[1013]:
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: This only seems to work when the values are not strings.

Comment: Yes, for strings, conditional values needs to be quotes.